# Is there a SQL SELECT to rename one column preserving column order?

Tags: sql

If I want to rename a column `foo`, I can write

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(foo), foo as bar
```

But that pushes foo to the end of the column list. Is there a way to do this and preserve order? (NB. the table has *many* columns, so I'm not looking to list them all.)

Edit: I don't think this is a duplicate. The main answer linked to says

> A SELECT * REPLACE statement **does not change the names** or order of columns.

Comment: as far as I can tell no. Which rdbms are you using?

Comment: As far as I'm aware not in standard SQL. But you could create a view without the colums you don't want. Then select * from the view. Or depending on the type of database use a dynamic sql.

Comment: @SNR Bigquery...

Comment: @Mohan I think it cannot be done. Try to change the name of the column in your dataset schema.